# Using junit test to pass command line argument to Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot

I have a very basic Spring Boot application, which is expecting an argument from command line, and without it doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private Reader reader;

    @Autowired
    private Writer writer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Assert.notEmpty(args);

        List<> cities = reader.get("Berlin");
         writer.write(cities);
    }
}
```

Here is my JUnit test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CityApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Now, `Assert.notEmpty()` mandates for passing an argument. However, now, I am writing JUnit test for the same. But, I get following exception raise from the `Assert`.

```
2016-08-25 16:59:38.714 ERROR 9734 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:801) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111) [spring-boot-test-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:46) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this array must not be empty: it must contain at least 1 element
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:222) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:234) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.deepakshakya.dev.Application.run(Application.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Any idea, how to pass the parameter?

Comment: To be honest, do you even want to test that? I would just create an additional profile, exclude the bean when that profile is used, use the profile in your integration tests and done. To test the `run()` method does what it should do you can always write an unit test, you don't have to start your application for that.

Comment: Also... you didn't show how you're starting the test, which gives us no clue about how you're trying to pass the arguments.

Comment: I have updated the JUnit class from where the application is called.

Comment: You should specify at leas one `command line` argument.

Comment: @AntonNovopashin I want to provide, but that is the question all about. Where should I specify that. I can do it in eclipse when I run it there, but what about if I want to run this on a CI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` has `args` param. You can pass cli arguments there

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#args--

Comment: springboot version should above 2.2.0

Answer (score 9):

I´ve managed to find a way to create Junit tests that worked fine with SpringBoot by injecting the ApplicationContext in my test and calling a CommandLineRunner with the required parameters.

The final code looks like that:

```
package my.package.

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AsgardBpmClientApplicationIT {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        CommandLineRunner runner = ctx.getBean(CommandLineRunner.class);
        runner.run ( "-k", "arg1", "-i", "arg2");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Test needs to be public though.

Comment: One comment/aclaration, if nothing it's do for avoid, the commandLine would be "loaded" before call it, and maybe if arguments are required this initialize fail.

Comment: Do not autowire the ApplicationContext. Simply autowire the CommandLineRunner.

Comment: @SvenDöring: Could you please provide a simple example?

Comment: Instead of ``@Autowired ApplicationContext ctx;`` Simply use: ``@Autowired YourCommandLineRunner runner;``.

Answer (score 6):

I'm affraid that your solution will not work in a way that you presented (until you implement your own test framework for Spring).

This is because when you are running tests, Spring (its test `SpringBootContextLoader` to be more specific) runs your application in its own way. It instantiates `SpringApplication` and invokes its `run` method without any arguments. It also never uses your `main` method implemented in application.

However, you could refactor your application in a way that it'll be possible to test it.

I think (since you are using Spring) the easiest solution could be implemented using spring configuration properties instead of pure command line arguments. (But you should be aware that this solution should be used rather for "configuration arguments", because that's the main purpose of springs `configuration properties` mechanism)

Reading parameters using `@Value` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${myCustomArgs.customArg1}")
    private String customArg1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Assert.notNull(customArg1);
        //...
    }
}
```

Sample test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest({"myCustomArgs.customArg1=testValue"})
public class CityApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

And when running your command line app just add your custom params:

`--myCustomArgs.customArg1=testValue`

Answer (score 4):

I would leave SpringBoot out of the equation.

You simply need to test the `run` method, without going through Spring Boot, since your goal is not to test spring boot, isn't it ?
I suppose, the purpose of this test is more for regression, ensuring that your application always throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when no args are provided? Good old unit test still works to test a single method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Application app = new Application();

    @Mock
    private Reader reader;

    @Mock
    private Writer writer;

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testNoArgs() throws Exception {
        app.run();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithArgs() throws Exception {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("test");
        Mockito.when(reader.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(list);

        app.run("myarg");

        Mockito.verify(reader, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).get(Mockito.anyString());
        Mockito.verify(writer, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).write(list);
    }
}
```

I used Mockito to inject mocks for Reader and Writer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Agree to your point. However, I was looking more from the functional test perspective and wanted to specifically test the execution of code by providing different values from command line. Seems like there isn't any way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

In your code autowire springs `ApplicationArguments`. Use `getSourceArgs()` to retrieve the commandline arguments.

```
public CityApplicationService(ApplicationArguments args, Writer writer){        
    public void writeFirstArg(){
        writer.write(args.getSourceArgs()[0]);
    }
}
```

In your test mock the ApplicationArguments.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CityApplicationTests {
@MockBean
private ApplicationArguments args;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        // given
        Mockito.when(args.getSourceArgs()).thenReturn(new String[]{"Berlin"});

        // when
        ctx.getBean(CityApplicationService.class).writeFirstArg();

        // then
        Mockito.verify(writer).write(Matchers.eq("Berlin"));

    }
}
```

---

Like *Maciej Marczuk* suggested, I also prefer to use Springs `Environment` properties instead of commandline arguments. But if you cannot use the springs syntax `--argument=value` you could write an own `PropertySource`, fill it with your commandline arguments syntax and add it to the `ConfigurableEnvironment`. Then all your classes only need to use springs Environment properties.

E.g.

```
public class ArgsPropertySource extends PropertySource<Map<String, String>> {

    ArgsPropertySource(List<CmdArg> cmdArgs, List<String> arguments) {
        super("My special commandline arguments", new HashMap<>());

        // CmdArgs maps the property name to the argument value.
        cmdArgs.forEach(cmd -> cmd.mapArgument(source, arguments));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return source.get(name);
    }
}


public class SetupArgs {

    SetupArgs(ConfigurableEnvironment env, ArgsMapping mapping) {           
        // In real world, this code would be in an own method.
        ArgsPropertySource = new ArgsPropertySource(mapping.get(), args.getSourceArgs());
        environment
            .getPropertySources()
            .addFirst(propertySource);
    }
}
```

---

BTW:

Since I do not have enough reputation points to comment an answer, I would still like to leave a hard learned lesson here:

The `CommandlineRunner` is not such a good alternative. Since its `run()` method alwyas gets executed right after the creation of the spring context. Even in a test-class. So it will run, before your Test started ...

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to

```
@SpringBootTest(args = "test")
class YourApplicationTests {
  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
  }
}
```

Comment: And you can take it with       if (args.length==0 || !args[0].equals("test"))  in your Spring Boot Application

Comment: Please use the [edit] button under the answer to put all of the information there, and then format code elements as code so that they're more readable. The [editing guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152753/121324), Spring Boot currently doesn't offer a way to intercept/replace the [DefaultApplicationArguments](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/DefaultApplicationArguments.html) that it uses. A natural-Boot-way that I used to solve this was to enhance my runner logic and use some autowired properties.

First, I created a properties component:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app") @Component @Data
public class AppProperties {
    boolean failOnEmptyFileList = true;
    boolean exitWhenFinished = true;
}
```

...autowired the properties component into my runner:

```
@Service
public class Loader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private AppProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public Loader(AppProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    ...
```

...and, in the `run` I only assert'ed when that property is enabled, which is defaulted to `true` for normal application usage:

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    if (properties.isFailOnEmptyFileList()) {
        Assert.notEmpty(args.getNonOptionArgs(), "Pass at least one filename on the command line");
    }

    // ...do some loading of files and such

    if (properties.isExitWhenFinished()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

With that, I can tweak those properties to execute in a unit test friendly manner:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "app.failOnEmptyFileList=false",
        "app.exitWhenFinished=false"
})
public class InconsistentJsonApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I needed the `exitWhenFinished` part since my particular runner normally calls `System.exit(0)` and exiting that way leaves the unit test in a semi-failed state.

Answer (score 0):

In Junit 5, simply we can pass commanline arguments using args parm present in @SpringBootTest(args = "20210831")

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(args = "20210831")
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test.class, TestConfig.class})
public class AppleTest {
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192086/979772